# Show $f$ is continuous map of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

The original problem asked is to show that $\frac{1}{m} < a - b < \frac{1}{m}$ implies $\frac{-1}{m} < f(a) - f(b) < \frac{1}{m}$ for every positive integer $m.$

It then asks to conclude $f$ is a continous map of $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume $f \in $ Aut$(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$.

I already did that part.

My approach was: $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0, m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, such that if $\delta > \epsilon $ thus $|a- b| < \frac{1}{m}$, and that implies $|f(a) - f(b)| < \frac{1}{m} < \epsilon$.

Now I am having trouble showing $f$ is continuous . Can someone please help me out? I am trying to use the definition.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{-1}{m}<a-b<\frac{1}{m}$?

Comment: yes . Sorry about the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Pick a natural number $m>\frac 1\epsilon$ and let $\delta=\frac 1m>0$. Then $|a-b|<\delta$ implies $|f(a)-f(b)|<\epsilon$, hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.